# Evalutate $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1+\frac{7}{x})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Evalutate $\frac{d}{dx}ln(1+\frac{7}{x})$

---

I tried using the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1+\frac{7}{x}) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{7}{x}}(\frac{d}{dx}(1+\frac{7}{x}))=\frac{1}{1+\frac{7}{x}}(\frac{-7}{x^2})=\frac{-7}{x^2+49x}$$

But the answer is supposed to be $\frac{-7}{x^2+7x}$

Comment: Where does this $49$ come from ?

Comment: You have a mistake in multiplication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is correct, except the last step where you introduced $49$.

You have $$\frac{1}{1+\frac{7}{x}}(\frac{-7}{x^2})=\frac{-7}{x^{2}(1+\frac{7}{x})}=\frac{-7}{x^2+7x}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln\left(1+\frac7x\right)\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln\left(\frac{x+7}{x}\right)\right]=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\ln(x+7)-\ln x\right]=\frac{1}{x+7}-\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Answer :

$$(\ln(1+7/x))' =\dfrac { (1+7/x)' }{(1+7/x)} =\dfrac { (-7/x^2)}{((x+7)/x)}= -\dfrac { 7}{x^2+7x}$$